# Error from JavaScript .sort() and .indexOf() methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexof

I have a function which is expected to return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be inserted into an array (first argument) once it has been sorted. The returned value should be a number.

getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5) should return 1 because  ***1.5*** is greater than ***1*** *(index 0)*, but less than ***2*** *(index 1)*.

The code executes as expected except when these argument are passed to it

*getIndexToIns([5, 3, 20, 3], 5);*
//should return **2** but return **0**

*getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15);*
//should return **3** but return **-1**

*getIndexToIns([], 1));* //should return **0** but return **-1**

Here's my code in JavaScript

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr = arr.sort();
  for(let i in arr){
   if(num < arr[i]){
arr.splice(i,0,num);

   } 
  }
  return arr.indexOf(num);
}
```

Comment: Why not just insert and then sort? - if you then want to know where it was inserted, look at the index of the inserted number

Comment: Are you aware that you are also changing the array? You even add `num` several times. That is probably not what you want. If you only want to return the theoretical index, it might be better to just iterate through the array and count the number of items that are smaller than `num`. The resulting number is the index.

Comment: @mplungjan, I tried                                       ```function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr.push(num);
  arr.sort();
  return arr.indexOf(num);
}```      But I got these errors   
  getIndexToIns([3, 10, 5], 3) should return 0.
getIndexToIns([5, 3, 20, 3], 5) should return 2.
getIndexToIns([2, 20, 10], 19) should return 2.
getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15) should return 3.

Comment: `const getIndexToIns = num => { arr.push(num); arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b); return arr.indexOf(num);}`

Comment: Without changing the array: `const getIndexToIns = num => { let newArr = arr.slice(0); newArr.push(num); newArr.sort((a,b)=>a-b); return newArr.indexOf(num);}`

Comment: Without changing the array, you don't have to sort it. Just loop and count smaller values like this: `var getIndexToIns = (arr, num) => arr.reduce((acc, val) => val < num ? ++acc : acc, 0);`